# similar values highlight in same row Excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel sheet data from B2: AF7. (data in 6 rows and 31 columns)

my need is...
if user input three values, then same row similar values from columns B2:AF7 should be highlight with color

values starts from B column. 
values like these 
sheet 1:

```
B column
1919106 
1825168
1856294
2038838
1891278
1799495
till column AF7
```

any solutions ...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary to show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question.

Comment: Formula based conditional formatting??

Comment: Please define "similar value", how close do they need to be "similar"

Comment: @Raj could you be more clear please?

Comment: Hi and welcome. "if user input three values" from this... where would the user input the values?

Answer (score 0):

For this question i use Sheet1 and yellow background.

Try:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim ImportValue As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim RowNo As Long
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("$B$2:$AF$7")) Is Nothing Then

        RowNo = Target.Row
        ImportValue = Target.Value

        For i = 2 To 32
          If ImportValue <> "" And ImportValue = Sheet1.Cells(RowNo, i).Value Then
            With Target.Interior
                .Color = 65535
            End With
            With Sheet1.Cells(RowNo, i).Interior
                .Color = 65535
            End With
          End If
        Next i

    End If

End Sub
```